# Select a field if it is not null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an entity which have two fields for name.

```
public class Place
{
    string EnglishName {get; set;}
    string LocalizedName {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

By default I want select LocalizedName but if LocalizedName was null then select EnglishName.
Is it possible to write a query like this in linq:

```
from place in _context.Places
where place.Slug == slug
select new { Name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(place.LocalizedName) 
                    ? place.LocalizedName 
                    : place.EnglishName }
```

Comment: and it doesn't work? please report any problems..

Comment: It might depend on wether `_context.Places` is IQueryable or just  IEnumerable. Youi should try this and post full error info.

Comment: I didn't try it, I just looking some thing like that.

Comment: Hey downvoter, what's the reason of downvote ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It will work. The full example:

```
public class Place
{
    public string EnglishName { get; set; }
    public string LocalizedName { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}
void Main()
{
  var places = new List<Place>
  {
    new Place { LocalizedName = "Localized1", EnglishName = "English1", Slug = "Slug" },    
    new Place { LocalizedName = null, EnglishName = "English2", Slug = "Slug" },
    new Place { LocalizedName = "Localized3", EnglishName = "English3", Slug = "Slug" },    
    new Place { LocalizedName = null, EnglishName = "English4", Slug = "Slug" },
  };
  var slug = "Slug";
  var names = 
      from place in  places
      where place .Slug == slug
      select new { Name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(place.LocalizedName ) 
                          ? place.LocalizedName 
                          : place.EnglishName };
  foreach (var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
// Displays:
// Localized1
// English2
// Localized3
// English4
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will search slug from the list and will return first match LocalizedName. If `LocalizedName` is null, it will return `EnglishName` of that place.

```
string placeName = _context.Places
                           .Where(place => place.Slug == slug)
                           .Select(place => place.LocalizedName ?? 
                            place.EnglishName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: this code will search slug from the list , and will return first match LocalizedName and  if LocalizedName is null , it will return EnglishName of that Place.

Comment: Can you put that in your answer ?